# Replacing DIV tag using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to add a link to a DIV tag with id attribute using sed command in external filter(ExtFilterDefine),

ExtFilterDefine nameX mode=output intype=text/html \ cmd="/bin/sed 's|<\div id="xxx">|<\div id="xxx">Click here <\a href=\"/pathX/x.html\"></a>|' ''

<\LocationMatch> .. </LocationMatch>

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help on this? It works fine if I add link to end of the div tag (</div>).But I wanted to add link to the start of the div tag.

Comment: why you escape `d, a`?

Comment: The content wasn't getting displayed until I added a escape

Comment: Basically I wanted to append the link with the div tag